# How to use UPDATE with a SELECT in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am using the latest MySQL.

I have two tables: `backlinks` and `pages`.

I am trying to update a column called `cache_links` in the table `pages` for a certain url. The column should equal the number of rows in `backlinks` where `destination` = `url`.

I could do this in my application language like so, in case what I mean to do isn't clear:

```
$myURL = "http://google.com/";

$numLinksResult = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT count(*) AS `num` FROM `backlinks` WHERE `same_domain` = FALSE AND `url` = '$myURL'");
$numLinksRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($numLinksResult);
$numLinks = $numLinksRow['num'];

mysqli_query($c, "UPDATE `pages` SET `links` = $numLinks WHERE `url` = '$myURL'");
```

The query I've been trying to build currently looks like this:

```
UPDATE `pages`, `backlinks` SET pages.`cache_links` = backlinks.count(*)
    WHERE  backlinks.`destination` = pages.`url`
        AND backlinks.`same_domain` = FALSE
        AND pages.`url` = 'http://google.com/'
```

The problem, I think, is at `backlinks.count(*)`. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The error I get is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)
WHERE backlinks.`destination` = pages.`url` AND backlinks.`same_' at line 1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub query.

```
UPDATE `pages`
SET    pages.`cache_links` =
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM    backlinks
       WHERE   backlinks.`destination` = pages.`url`
       AND     backlinks.`same_domain` = FALSE
       )
WHERE  pages.`url` = 'http://google.com/'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I love you–thanks a ton! I'll accept your answer in ~7 minutes when I can.

Comment: You answered this in 2 mins! That must be some kind of a speed record. +1!